# How can i convert account format from 101000002035 to 101-000002-03-5 in MySql

Tags: mysql

It is possible to convert account column value from 101000002035 to 101-000002-03-5 in MySql?

Please help.
How can i do it.

Comment: Use `CONCAT` and `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat_ws and substr.  Substr will slice the string according to length while Concat will stitch them together.

```
See example below.

Set @str:= '101000002035';

select concat_ws('-', 
       substr(@str, 1, 3), 
       substr(@str, 4, 6), 
       substr(@str, 10, 2),
       substr(@str, 12, 1));

Result: 101-000002-03-5
```

Comment: Thanks @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ